# stop IntentService from Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

I need help with this situation:

1. I have activity, what starts IntentService.
2. Service do some job in while cycle and sleep for some time.
3. Main cycle of service is endless, so I need to stop it from activity again.
4. I must be able to end activity, start it again and stop IntentService from new "instance" of activity.

   ```
   public class MyService extends IntentService {

       public MyService()
       {
           super("MyService");
       }

       public MyService(String name) {
           super(name);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
           Log.d("SERVICE", "start");

           while(true)
           {
               SystemClock.sleep(1000);
               Log.d("SERVICE", "tick");
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onDestroy() {
           Log.d("SERVICE", "end");
           super.onDestroy();
       }
   ```

...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
startService(intent);
```

I tried calling `stopService()`, but it's not working. Is there any solution how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Service do some job in while cycle and sleep for some time.

IMHO, this is an inappropriate use of `IntentService`. Please create a regular `Service`, with your own background thread that you manage yourself.

> Is there any solution how to do this?

Create a regular `Service`, with your own background thread that you manage yourself. For example, you could use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of your `sleep()` loop, using `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` in the service's `onDestroy()`.